# Populating child drop down based on what was selected from parent drop down list

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, razor

I am using the latest version of jQuery and ASP.NET MVC 3 with the Razor view engine.

I have tried Google looking for a decent example of loading a child drop down list when a parent drop down item is selected.  I am looking to do this via `jQuery` `AJAX` using `JSON`.  My knowledge of this is zero.

I have a Category class with a list of categories.  It's a parent-child association.

If I select a category from the parent drop down list, then all the child categories need to be listed in the child drop down list for the selected parent category.

This is what I currently have, but need to complete it, not sure if I am in the right direction:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#ddlParentCategories').change(function () {
      alert('changed');
   });
});
```

I loaded my drop down list from my view model as such:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ParentCategoryId, new SelectList(Model.ParentCategories, "Id", "Name", Model.ParentCategoryId), "-- Select --", new { id = "ddlParentCategories" })
```

The first item has text "-- Select --" (for both parent and child drop down lists).  On initial page load nothing must be loaded in the child drop down list.  When a value is selected then the child drop down list must be populated.  And when "-- Select --" is selected again in the parent drop down list then all the items in the child drop down list must cleared except "-- Select --".

If possible, if the child categories is loading, how do I display that "round" loading icon?

**UPDATE**

I have updated my code to Darin's code, and I cannot get it to work properly:

`Category` class:

```
public class Category
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
   public string MetaKeywords { get; set; }
   public string MetaDescription { get; set; }
   public bool IsActive { get; set; }
   public int? ParentCategoryId { get; set; }
   public virtual Category ParentCategory { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Category> ChildCategories { get; set; }
}
```

`EditProductViewModel` class:

```
public class EditProductViewModel
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
   public string LongDescription { get; set; }
   public bool IsActive { get; set; }
   public string PageTitle { get; set; }
   public bool OverridePageTitle { get; set; }
   public string MetaKeywords { get; set; }
   public string MetaDescription { get; set; }
   public int ParentCategoryId { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<Category> ParentCategories { get; set; }
   public int ChildCategoryId { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<Category> ChildCategories { get; set; }
}
```

`ProductController` class:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
   EditProductViewModel viewModel = new EditProductViewModel
   {
      ParentCategories = categoryService.GetParentCategories()
         .Where(x => x.IsActive)
         .OrderBy(x => x.Name),
      ChildCategories = Enumerable.Empty<Category>(),
      IsActive = true
   };

   return View(viewModel);
}

public ActionResult AjaxBindingChildCategories(int parentCategoryId)
{
   IEnumerable<Category> childCategoryList = categoryService.GetChildCategoriesByParentCategoryId(parentCategoryId);

   return Json(childCategoryList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

`Create` view:

```
<tr>
   <td><label>Parent Category:</label> <span class="red">*</span></td>
   <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ParentCategoryId,
         new SelectList(Model.ParentCategories, "Id", "Name", Model.ParentCategoryId),
         "-- Select --",
         new { data_url = Url.Action("AjaxBindingChildCategories"), id = "ParentCategories" }
      )
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.ParentCategoryId)
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><label>Child Category:</label> <span class="red">*</span></td>
   <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ChildCategoryId,
         new SelectList(Model.ChildCategories, "Id", "Name", Model.ChildCategoryId),
         "-- Select --",
         new { id = "ChildCategories" }
      )
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.ChildCategoryId)
   </td>
</tr>

<script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#ParentCategories').change(function () {
         var url = $(this).data('url');
         var data = { parentCategoryId: $(this).val() };

         $.getJSON(url, data, function (childCategories) {
            var childCategoriesDdl = $('#ChildCategories');
            childCategoriesDdl.empty();

            $.each(childCategories, function (index, childCategory) {
               childCategoriesDdl.append($('<option/>', {
                  value: childCategory, text: childCategory
               }));
            });
         });
      });
   });


</script>
```

It goes into my AjaxBindingChildCategories action and it brings back records, it just doesn't want to display my child category dropdownlist.  I had a look in Fire Bug and the error that I get is:

```
GET AjaxBindingChildCategories?parentCategoryId=1

500 Internal Server Error
```

Comment: What you are asking about is called a "Cascading Dropdown." That will help when Googling.

Comment: Ok thanks, let me go and search further :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example of cascading drop down lists. As always start by defining a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [DisplayName("Country")]
    [Required]
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Countries { get; set; }

    public string City { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Cities { get; set; }
}
```

then a controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MyViewModel
        {
            // TODO: Fetch countries from somewhere
            Countries = new[]
            {
                new SelectListItem { Value = "FR", Text = "France" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "US", Text = "USA" },
            },

            // initially we set the cities ddl to empty
            Cities = Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>()
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    public ActionResult Cities(string countryCode)
    {
        // TODO: based on the selected country return the cities:
        var cities = new[]
        {
            "Paris", "Marseille", "Lyon"
        };
        return Json(cities, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

a view:

```
@model MyViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.CountryCode)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(
            x => x.CountryCode, 
            Model.Countries, 
            "-- Select country --", 
            new { data_url = Url.Action("cities") }
        )
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.CountryCode)
    </div>

    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.City)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(
            x => x.City, 
            Model.Cities, 
            "-- Select city --"
        )
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.City)
    </div>

    <p><input type="submit" value="OK" /></p>
}
```

and finally the unobtrusive javascript in a separate file:

```
$(function () {
    $('#CountryCode').change(function () {
        var url = $(this).data('url'); 
        var data = { countryCode: $(this).val() };
        $.getJSON(url, data, function (cities) {
            var citiesDdl = $('#City');
            citiesDdl.empty();
            $.each(cities, function (index, city) {
                citiesDdl.append($('<option/>', {
                    value: city,
                    text: city
                }));
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Darin.  I want to use the same code for my Edit page (this is currently for my Create page).  How would I use it so that it selects the country and city when it is loaded?

Comment: I actually have city Id and name.  How would the above code change to accommodate this?

Comment: @Brendan Vogt, you could add a `Cities` property to your view model which is of type `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` and have your Edit action fill it with the corresponding cities to the selected country. Then inside the Edit view use the following to generate the cities ddl: `@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.City, Model.Cities, "-- Select city --")`. I have updated my answer to include this property to the view model.

Comment: I am working through your code line by line.  I just did an alert on url and data variables and they came back with nothing in them, is this correct?

Comment: What is cities in $.getJSON(url, data, function (cities) { ?  How is this being populated?

Comment: @Brendan Vogt, the url is fetched as HTML5 `data-url="/home/cities"` attribute from the countries ddl (notice the fourth parameter passed to the `DropDownListFor` ddl). As far as the `cities` variable it is the argument passed by jQuery to the anonymous success callback of the AJAX request. In this case it is a simple array of cities as that's what the Cities controller action returns as JSON object.

Comment: Darin, I modified the original post, and added an update section.  I tried to update my code as to what you posted.  There is still some confusion as to the use of cities and city, I left it in above for your sake.  I got confused between Cities and cities, you used it interchangeably in data_url = Url.Action("cities").  Can you please update my code so that I can get this to work.  Another thing is that when a parent category is selected the child drop down must be cleared (which seems to happen), but I need the -- Select -- part to be there for the child drop down.  Please update :)

Comment: @Brendan Vogt, what doesn't work with your code? Are you getting some error? Is the AJAX request sent? What happened when you analyzed it in FireBug? Why are you using domain objects such as `Category` in your view model? That's not a real view model. A real view model should not have any reference to any domain object. Maybe this `Category` domain object has some circular references in its hierarchy making it impossible to JSON serialize?

Comment: Please see my updated post.  Not sure what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: It looks like an exception is thrown in your AjaxBindingChildCategories method. Probably the `categoryService.GetChildCategoriesByParentCategoryId(parentCategoryId);`. What happened when you tried to debug your code?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery script will look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getCities(abbr) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("Cities", "Locations")",
        data: {abbreviation: abbr},
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        error: function() {
            alert("An error occurred.");
        },
        success: function(data) {
            var items = "";
            $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                items += "<option value=\"" + item.Value + "\">" + item.Text + "</option>";
            });

            $("#City").html(items);
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#State").change(function() {
        var abbr = $("#State").val();

        getCities(abbr);
    });
});
</script>
```

A repository to retrieve data could look like this (obviously hook it up to live data though):

```
public class LocationRepository : ILocationRepository
{
    public IQueryable<State> GetStates()
    {
        return new List<State>
        {
            new State { Abbreviation = "NE", Name = "Nebraska" },
            new State { Abbreviation = "NC", Name = "North Carolina" }
        }.AsQueryable();
    }

    public IQueryable<City> GetCities(string abbreviation)
    {
        var cities = new List<City>();

        if (abbreviation == "NE")
        {
            cities.AddRange(new List<City> {
                new City { Id = 1, Name = "Omaha" },
                new City { Id = 2, Name = "Lincoln" }
            });
        }
        else if (abbreviation == "NC")
        {
            cities.AddRange(new List<City> {
                new City { Id = 3, Name = "Charlotte" },
                new City { Id = 4, Name = "Raleigh" }
            });
        }

        return cities.AsQueryable();
    }
}

public interface ILocationRepository
{
    IQueryable<State> GetStates();
    IQueryable<City> GetCities(string abbreviation);
}
```

Controllers could look like this:

```
public class LocationsController : Controller
{
    private ILocationRepository locationRepository = new LocationRepository();

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult States()
    {
        var states = locationRepository.GetStates();

        return Json(new SelectList(state, "Id", "Name"));
    } 

     [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Cities(string abbreviation)
    {
        var cities = locationRepository.GetCities(abbreviation);

        return Json(new SelectList(cities, "Abbreviation", "Name")); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but can I please see your HTML for the 2 dropdowns?  You can see from my post how I populate the parent category.  How would you construct the child category, also from the view model?

Comment: Please see my updated post.  Not sure what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you populate the parent dropdown from server side and also the first option in this parent dd is `"--- Select ---"`

You can try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var $parent = $('#ddlParentCategories');

   var $child = $('#ddlChildCategories');
   $child.find("option:gt(0)").remove();

   if(!$parent.children().eq(0).is(":selected")){

     $parent.change(function () {
        $.ajax({
          url: "urlToFetchTheChild",
          data: { categoryId: this.value },
          success: function(data){  
            //The data you send should be a well formed array of json object containing code/value pair of child categories

            for(var i = 0;i<data.length;i++){
               $child.append("<option value='"+ data[i].code +"'>"+ data[i].value +"</option>"); 
            }

          }
        });
     });
   }


});
```

Comment: Please see my updated post.  Not sure what I am doing wrong here?